# How do I authenticate my electron application using an USB fingerprint scanning device?

Tags: javascript, usb, electron, fingerprint

I have an application written in electronJS. I want to enable authentication via a USB fingerprint scanning device. Can this be achieved with any USB fingerprint(FP) scanning device or do I need to look up for the one which exposes javascript SDK? Does there exist such FP scanning device?